# Heroku detects Clojure app as Node.js one

Tags: node.js, heroku, clojure

Heroku detects app type by presence of files like `package.json` or `project.clj`.

I am trying to build Clojure app, so I have `project.clj` in my root directory. But I also use some node.js tools, so I have `package.json` too.

Is there a way to tell Heroku what kind of app I build, but keep `package.json`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a .slugignore file with the contents `package.json` and Heroku will not see that file, even though it will be in your git archive.